# Arranging Stacked Bar Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been fiddling with a stacked bar chart, which I cannot get to sort from tallest to shortest.  Here is the chart I have currently.

[stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9zsx.png)

[df7.csv](https://empire-share.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/df7.csv)

The code I am using is below:

```html
ggplot(df7, aes(
  x = reorder(cause, failures) ,
  y = failures,
  fill = factor(
    part_number,
    levels = c(
      "UNKNOWN",
      "3766453",
      "20R7920",
      "3966006",
      "3976397",
      "20R7916",
      "20R7915"
    )
  )
)) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "stack",
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.7,
    alpha = 0.75,
    color = 'black'
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('Failures') +
  labs(fill = "Part Number") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  coord_flip()
```

Does anyone see why the chart is not sorting correctly?  Thank you, and cheers!

Comment: Please add `df7` or a sample of it with `dput(df7)` in order to reproduce your issue!

Comment: I have added a link to the df7 dataset.

Comment: By default `reorder` uses `FUN=mean`. Try `reorder(cause, failures, FUN=sum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reorder` is a generic function for reordering factors. By default it reorders by mean. By default `reorder` uses a 'mean' function (`FUN = mean` by default) to reorder factors.  By setting the FUN argument to `sum` reorder will sort the stacked columns by the sum total of the components to each bar.

The reorder section of the code should be replaced with the following:

```
reorder(cause, failures, FUN=sum)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, your answer could be useful for OP but you can make it better with explaining things.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back.  I add more information to the solution.  Cheers!